# How can I tell if a Pardot list has been archived using the API?

Tags: api, pardot

I'm using the Pardot API to pull a list of all the Lists that we can assign prospects to.  My query includes lists that we've "archived" in Pardot, but there's nothing in the JSON result that tells me the status of a list.

I have a related issue with Prospect queries.  The list membership returned for a prospect includes membership in lists that we've deleted, but there's nothing to indicate this in the JSON so it looks like the prospect is part of many more lists than they actually are.  I can cross reference the prospects lists against my first query, I suppose, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible via the API.

I maintain pypardot4, the Python wrapper for the Pardot API, so I know the API pretty well however I don't work for Pardot and am not an expert.